# Optimise build time for a huge swift project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compilation, build-time

I have a huge swift project which has more than 70 Storyboards and 1269 XIBs and 14 compileswiftsources. Its taking 16 to 35 minutes. As I can see most of the compile-time was due to storyboards and XIBs.

I have done all the optimizations.

- Disabling DSYM
- Optimisation level is the fastest.
- Try all things mention in the blog -> https://www.avanderlee.com/optimization/analysing-build-performance-xcode/

Can anybody suggests how can I optimize compile time.

I am sharing build time summary.

[image]

Comment: Recently I faced the same situation, but unfortunately I didn’t manage to decrease the build time in an effective way. The only acceptable result came when I rewrite some of the biggest .storyboard / .xib files to .swift files (I mean create the UI programmatically instead of the xml files). Not the best solution tho, need a lot of resource (time), and it can create some bugs / errors of course.